# How to get uploaded tracks from soundcloud?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, soundcloud

I have implemented Sound cloud api in my app to export songs to soundcloud.

Now,I want to launch a browser in my app.This browser will allow the user to browse and listen to various other users songs that have been exported to SoundCloud through my app.
Also,the songlist should not include tracks which are not uploaded through my app.

The following is a screenshot from an app which uses similar functionality:
[image]

The only change in my app will be that I dont want the Sessions list.
Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Good Questions if some one know this please answer , I m also in need for the answer of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am with an answer for my question. wat a relief.. :)

To get the app id first, the url is to be resolved by:

http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://soundcloud.com/apps/{appName}

With this, you will get your app id.

(For more on Resolver, can refer to the link : https://github.com/soundcloud/api/wiki/12-Resolver)

Now, you can get tracks created with your app like this: 
http://api.soundcloud.com/apps/{app-id}/tracks

For the browser look, it is to be customised on your own. Its not a standard from SoundCloud.